# Refreezing already thawed bread

Tags: food-safety

I bought a loaf of bread some weeks ago, which the lady behind the counter explained was frozen (because it was leftover). This was okay for me. The bread was still frozen when I bought it and I let it defrost on the counter overnight.

Then we didn't eat all the bread (just about 50%) and I decided to put the leftover half back in the freezer (before it would spoil).

Now I'm wondering: Is it ok to rethaw and eat the bread? I know there are several threads/questions regarding freezing - thawing - refreezing, but they don't handle bread (which I would believe to act differently than i.e. meat).

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to freeze and rethaw bread, although it might not help with the quality.   Toasting it when you are finally ready to eat it will help bring out its best qualities.

Comment: If the quality of your bread was compromised by its time in the freezer consider using it to make french toast.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained in the accepted answer, this might compromise the flavor of the bread. It will tend to taste stale.

What I usually do with bread like this after thawing, is to make bread crumbs with it (if I don't decide to make a bread pudding with it). There is always breadcrumbs in my freezer, and they last for months. Here is how

**STEP 1**

Break the bread into managable size to fit into a food processor

**STEP 2**

Blitz the bread until the desired texture is reached. I tend to keep mine quite course

**STEP 3**

Spread these crumbs evenly on a oven pan and place in the oven at +/- 100 degrees celsius until the crumbs goes golden brown (or to your own liking)

**STEP 4**

Let the crumbs cool down. I usually give them a quick blitz in the food processor before storing them to break them apart again as they usually clump together in the oven

Transfer them to an airtight vessel and place in your freezer. They will last for months.